# Implementing max-margin loss in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

I want to implement Max-margin loss in tensorflow. It is the sum of k such terms:

> `max(0, a + cos(y, y')-cos(y_i, y'))`
>   , where y is the target value, y' is the predicted value and y_1, ..., y_k are some k negative examples.

A heuristic is to choose negative example which are near to y' but far from y. The choice of negative examples thus depends on the output of the model.

Currently, I run the session to get y' as the output numpy array. Then I get the negative examples using the scikit Nearest Neighbor functionality which I pass to the model as placeholders.

The model computes y' again and can do the backpropagation since it can now compute the loss.

Is there a way that the model only does the forward computation once and I can use the scikit library to compute the nearest neighbors?

Comment: Your description of what your network does is not so clear. Couldn't you pass the y' you get from the first run to the second run with a placeholder ? This would avoid recomputing them.

Comment: If I do this, how will the model do the backpropagation to update its parameters? The activities of the hidden units are needed to do it and they are lost if I simply pass the y' as a placeholder. I might be missing something as I am new to Tensorflow.